# .net DropDownList gets cleared after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

This has been driving me nuts all day. I've seen this problem crop up here a few times, essentially I have a drop down list that populates a form below when it's changed - basic stuff. On first page load everything is fine, but when the dropdownlist is changed, it's entirely blank after postback and the SelectedIndexChanged event never fires. I believe it all points to a viewstate problem. Here's the code..

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EditUser.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_EditUser" %>
<asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ID="UsersList" EnableViewState="true"
    runat="server" DataTextField="EXTRANET_USER_EMAIL" DataValueField="EXTRANET_USER_ID">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and the pageload...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        IEnumerable<ExtranetUser> users = Users();
        UsersList.DataSource = users;
        UsersList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select User --", "0"));
        UsersList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated! I'm sure it's something simple...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Completely new answer...

Are you adding the control in the Page_Init event? Any later than this and the ViewState will have already been parsed and applied to the controls on the page, before the dynamically added control has been added. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) I'm afraid the same problem occurs with or without the items collection. Also, the list builds fine on the first page load.

Comment: You can combine the 2.  Set the AppendDataBoundItems="true" property on the DDL.  However, since the OP says it is fine on the initial page load and only seeing unexpected behavior after the postback, I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: I have just noticed that this is a user control. Is it being added to the page dynamically?

Comment: Yes it is! Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the EnableViewState on the Page directives also

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" EnableViewState="True" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EditUser.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_EditUser" %>
```

Also, the ordering of the items on postback are important to preserve the ViewState.
could it be, that after postback, some controls bevore that one are missing?

Comment: Sadly I've tried enabling viewstate all the way up the chain and it's done nothing.